# Entering different inputs from text field to labels in swift

Tags: swift, button, input, label, textfield

I have 1 `TextField`and 3 `Labels`. I need it to where I type in the box and hit enter it sends the input to first label then resets the `TextField`. Next I type in new data and hit enter again, without changing `Label1` text I need that new input in `Label2`.

Next I type in the new data and hit enter again, without changing label 1 text I need that the new input is put in label 2.

Names are valueLbl1, valueLbl2, valueLbl3, textField

```
valueLbl1.text = textField.text
if valueLbl1.text == textField.text {textField.text = ""}
if textField.text == "" {valueLbl2.text = textField.text }
```

Comment: share what you tried so far.

Comment: mind you this is all in the @ibaction button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ViewDidLoad()` set,

```
valueLbl1.text = ""
valueLbl2.text = ""
textField.text = ""
```

When typing done in `TextField` in delegate method

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if valueLbl1.text.isEmpty == true{
         valueLbl1.text = textField.text
         textField.text = ""
         return
    }
    else if valueLbl2.text.isEmpty == true{
         valueLbl2.text = textField.text
         textField.text = ""
         return
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Thank you, would I put that all labels equal text field then button action?

Comment: If you want to do the same thing for button click you can implement the same logic in your action method.

Comment: thank you very much I did not know about .isEmpty have been stuck on this for a while and new to Swift. Much appreciation!

Comment: i didn't need the func textFieldDoneEditing, but I implemented the fixes and yes its running smooth! Now I just need to figure out how to randomly hide 1 out of 2 or 2 out of 3 labels with another button

Comment: Firstly your question was to do the job with textfield input, that's why I answered like that. Now your requirement changed but Same logic works in both I answered. So you should accept my answer.

Comment: oh I do accept your answer, thank you very much! I'm grateful for your help, I'm not saying its not what I needed at all. It was just part of the code I'm using